# Schema design for Google BigTable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigtable

In my project, Im using Google BigQuery that holds loots of data.
The BigQuery columns are:

account_id, session_id, transaction_id, username, event, timestamp.

In my dashboard, Im fetching the entire data based on time stamp (last 30 days).
Since I have very large data, the performance are pretty slow (13 sec to fetch the last 30 days data).

Lately, I try to look on Google BigTable and I saw they have an option to get data based on time.
In my tests, the performance of  the BigTable are slower from the BigQuery.
Is any suggested schema that can improve the performance with BigTable?

This is example to my schema in BigTable:

```
  const row = {
    key: `transactions#${timestamp_micros}`,
    data: {
      identifiers: {
        session_id: `session_id-${startCounter}`,
        account_id: `acount-${startCounter}`,
        device_id: `device-${startCounter}`,
        transaction_id: `transaction_id-${startCounter}`,
        runtime_id: 'AQW+2Xx5AQAAstvxskK0c8NTk+vP5eBM',
        page_id: `page_id-${startCounter}`,
        start_time: timestamp,
      },
    },
  };
```

Is anyone can suggest a better schema that will help me to fetch the data (based on timestamp range) with the best performance?

Comment: I have provided an answer below to your question. Can you check if this helps you or anything else you want to ask?

Answer (score 0):

A good schema results in excellent performance and scalability, and a bad schema can lead to a poorly performing system. However, no single schema design provides the best fit for all use cases and hence your question is opinionated and will vary from person to person. The [patterns described on this page](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design-time-series) provide a starting point to decide a schema for BigTable. Your unique dataset and the queries you plan to use are the most important things to consider as you design a schema for your time-series data.

As you've discovered from our docs, the [row key](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design#row-keys) format is the biggest decision you make when using Bigtable, as it determines which access patterns can be performed efficiently. Having row key  `transaction_id#reverse_timestamp`gets your data sorted from the latest timestamp. This could avoid hotspotting issues, which is one of the big reasons for slow query results.

However, you're also coming from a SQL architecture, which isn't always a good fit for Bigtable's schema/query model. So here are some questions to get you started:

- Are you planning to perform lots of ad hoc queries like "SELECT A
  FROM Bigtable WHERE B=x"? If so, strongly prefer BigQuery. Bigtable
  can't support this query without performing a full table scan. (hence
  it is slower than BigQuery)
- Will you require multi-row OLTP transactions? Again, use BigQuery, as
  Bigtable only supports transactions within a single row.
- Are you streaming in new events at high QPS? Bigtable is much better
  for these sorts of high-volume updates. Do you want to perform any
  sort of large-scale complex transformations on the data? Again,
  Bigtable is likely better here, as you can stream data out and back
  in faster.

You can also combine the two services if you need some combination of these features. For example, say you're receiving high-volume updates all the time, but want to be able to perform complex ad hoc queries. If you're alright working with a slightly delayed version of the data, it could make sense to write the updates to Bigtable, then periodically scan the table using Dataflow and export a post-processed version of the latest events into BigQuery. GCP also allows BigQuery to serve queries directly from Bigtable in a some regions: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-bigtable

My personal choice for your use case is Big Query. You can leverage the  pruning in Big Query where BigQuery scans the partitions that match the filter and skip the remaining partitions. Not only does it make it easier to manage and query your data. By dividing a large table into smaller partitions, you can improve query performance, and you can control costs by reducing the number of bytes read by a query. You can use [time-unit column partitioning](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#query_a_time-unit_column-partitioned_table) or [ingestion time partitioning](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#query_an_ingestion-time_partitioned_table). When you create a table partitioned by ingestion time, BigQuery automatically assigns rows to partitions based on the time when BigQuery ingests the data. You can choose hourly, daily, monthly, or yearly granularity for the partitions.
So your query for fetching the entire data based on timestamp (last 30 days) should be something like this in BigQuery (when used partitioning):

```
SELECT
  column
FROM
  dataset.table
WHERE
  _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01') AND TIMESTAMP('2016-01-02')
```